# Binary search for the first element whose square is greater or equal to k

Tags: python, binary-search

I'm writing a piece of code to find the index of the first element in a sorted list whose square is greater or equal to a certain k. I used ordinary binary search as framework and modified it to meet my need. My idea is, the first element whose square is greater or equal to a certain k should have itself greater or equal to k and the element to its left (list is sorted) should have its square smaller than k. I put these conditions into consideration and the program only return the right answer when the right answer is index 1 (the "4" in the list), and it returns -1 right away with most another k. I tried to debug it but with no success, please help me out! thank you!

```
def Bsearch(a, k):
    high = len(a) - 1
    low = 0
    while high > low:
        mid = (high - low) // 2
        num = a[mid] * a[mid]
        left = a[mid - 1] * a[mid - 1]
        if num >= k and left < k:
            return mid
        elif left >= k:
            return Bsearch(a[:mid], k)
        elif num < k:
            return Bsearch(a[mid + 1:], k)
    return -1

a = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 19, 20]
k = 45
print(Bsearch(a, k))
```

Comment: its supposed to be `mid = low + (high-low)//2`.

Comment: you can use the root of K